# How to get permissions in local machine for Google Cloud apis (firestore)

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am new to fireStore and trying to retrieve document values but it isn't working as I would expect.  I am getting a "permission denied" when trying to access through my IDE and golang.

Code:

```
func TestConnectToCollection(t *testing.T) {

    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, "<my-Project-ID>")
    if err != nil {
        // TODO: Handle error.
    }
    defer client.Close()
    doc := client.Doc("profile/test3")
    fmt.Println(doc)
    fmt.Println(doc.ID)

    iter := client.Collection("profile").Documents(ctx)
    for {
        doc, error := iter.Next()
        if error == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if error != nil {
            fmt.Println(error.Error())
        } else {
            fmt.Println(doc.Data())
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
&{0xc0001725a0 projects/<project-id>/databases/(default)/documents/profile/test3 test3}
test3
rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Missing or insufficient permissions.
rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Missing or insufficient permissions.
rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Missing or insufficient permissions.
rpc error: code = PermissionDenied desc = Missing or insufficient permissions.
```

Firestore rules - I opened up my firestore rules thinking that was the issue.

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this work by changing the following configuration.

Go to Project Overview -> Project Settings -> Service accounts -> "Firebase Admin SDK" -> "Generate new private key" -> "Generate"

[image]

Then you see a popup like below

[image]

It took me an hour to figure this out. I hope this saves all your time!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, It's sad [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-go) only provides the most difficult ways to do it, as beginner it's important to make as easy as posible at first, but anyway these are the easiest steps to do it:

If you already have log in the console, jump to step 5

1. Intall [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/)
2. Run on your command line `gcloud auth login`
3. Login with the google account that owns the project
4. In your code, your configuration client should be like this:

   ```
   ctx := context.Background()
   client, err := firestore.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatal(err)
   }
   ```
5. Run on your command line `gcloud beta auth application-default login`

And that's it! it's like magic, I had too much headache trying the other ways.
This works for [cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) too and any google cloud api I'll guess

About your code:

```
client.Doc("profile/test3")
```

You are not getting any document at all there, it's just creat a [*DocumentRef](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentRef), in order to get the document you should do:

```
    ctx:=context.Background()
    snapShot,err:=client.Doc("profile/test3").Get(ctx)
    if err!=nil{
    log.Println(err)
    return err
    }
    var myStruct myStructType
    if err=snapShot.DataTo(&myStruct);err!=nil{
    log.Println(err)
    return err
    }
```

Read [documentation](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore) for more info

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore) tell me that [`Doc()`](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#Client.Doc) returns a [`*DocumentRef`](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentRef), a *reference* to the document. To fetch the document itself, you should call [`Get()`](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentRef.Get) on it, which gives you a [`*DocumentSnapshot`](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentSnapshot), and finally call [`Data()`](https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#DocumentSnapshot.Data) on that.

```
ref := client.Doc("profile/test3")
snap, err := ref.Get(ctx)
// FIXME error checking
data := snap.Data()
```

Comment: Thank you. I attempted many different ways (including the way that you recommend).   It appears to be a permissions error.   I don't really know where it is getting thrown though.   My local gcloud is hte owner of GCP Project.   But it looks like I am getting a "Missing or insufficient permissions" error.